# Вывод юзеров за период

Tags: sql, select

В БД есть таблица users, со значением db_users (дата рождения) в формате 2000-10-29 как вывести на сайт показ юзеров у которых день рождения в текущем календарном месяце.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE MONTH(date_of_birth) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

где `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())` число текущего месяца.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду благодарен если подскажите ещё как правильно эту выборку прописать?

Comment: @AOf *...как правильно эту выборку прописать?* - что Вы имеете ввиду ? Если Ваш запрос, то в `WHERE` добавьте `AND MONTH(u.db_user) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())`

Comment: Посмотрите скрин по ссылке пожалуйста. Правильно ли я сделал - (https://monosnap.com/file/b5S7LDYrRhxo0aM3685ur6vvZxZCYX)

Comment: @AOf в коде, указанном на скриншоте, Вы получите `id` всех пользователей у которых день рождения в текущем месяце. 
P.S.: **всегда** пишите код, а не делайте скриншоты, в т.ч. и в вопросах.

Comment: @AOf чтобы отобразить и иные поля как то: `name`, `email`, `phone` и пр. добавьте их в запрос.

Comment: этот запрос - $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 
     u.id, u.name, u.db_user, u.email, u.phone, u.city, 
     sc.id, c.id, c.id as code_id, 
     sc.id as scan_counts_id, u.id as u_user_id
    FROM users as u
    LEFT JOIN scan_counts AS sc ON sc.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN codes as c ON sc.code_id = c.id
    WHERE c.user_id = {$_SESSION['user']['id']} AND c.id = sc.code_id
    ORDER BY u.name ASC";   выводит данные all users Мне ЕЩЁ нужно ДОБАВИТЬ вывод тех у кого др в тек. меc  $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE MONTH(db_user) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()), email, phone, name";   ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ ЭТО?

Comment: @AOf Вы хотите, чтобы этот запрос выводил только данные клиентов у которых день рождения в этом месяце ?

Comment: нет этот выполняет свое действие правильно

Comment: добавить надо вывод тех у кого др

Comment: `SELECT id` выведет только их id. Аналогично Вашему запросу следующий запрос выведет только тех пользователей у которых день рождения в данном месяце. `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, u.db_user, u.email, u.phone, u.city, sc.id, c.id, c.id as code_id, sc.id as scan_counts_id, u.id as u_user_id FROM users as u LEFT JOIN scan_counts AS sc ON sc.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN codes as c ON sc.code_id = c.id WHERE c.user_id = {$_SESSION['user']['id']} AND c.id = sc.code_id AND MONTH(u.db_user) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) ORDER BY u.name ASC";` https://pastebin.com/6qAEFTEq

Comment: Спасибо. А смогу ли я выводить на одной странице две разные таблицы данных с помощью этого запроса пример на скрине :(https://monosnap.com/file/nVJfmc0V2yc1LAmYaOHzz3wy7RlDNk)

Comment: @AOf лучше использовать два запроса, по 1 на таблицу

Comment: @AOf если ответ Вам помог отметьте его как [решение Вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса